# Type hint: Python method that returns List of objects of it's containing class type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to give a give a code hint for a method that gets a list of objects of its containing class type

The error i'm getting is `'name 'PlayersOnline_Result' is not defined'`

I've tried to define the import for the class but that did not work:
`from data import PlayersOnline_Result`

```
from typing import List

class PlayersOnline_Result(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.fk_server : str = kwargs['fk_server']
        self.number_of_players_connected : int = kwargs.get('number_of_players_connected')
        self.number_of_total_players : int = kwargs.get('number_of_total_players')
        self.date : datetime = kwargs.get('date')

    @classmethod
    def execute(cls, session) -> List[PlayersOnline_Result]:
        query = 'call PlayersOnline'

        query_result = session.execute(query).fetchall()

        result : List[PlayersOnline_Result] =  list(map(PlayersOnline_Result.bind , query_result))

        return result

    @staticmethod
    def bind(x) :
        return PlayersOnline_Result(fk_server = x[0],
                                number_of_players_connected= x[1],
                                number_of_total_players= x[2],
                                date= x[3])
```

I'm calling `execute()` from another class:

```
    result = PlayersOnline_Result.execute(self._session)
```

PlayersOnline_Result is the model (dto) of the result of a stored procedure called with sqlalchemy.  If i remove the code hint: `-> List[PlayersOnline_Result]`, everything works great!

I'm new to python so be gentle on me! (plus my first question on SO)

(PS, I know I should probably be using a view instead of a stored proc with no params...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing hints PyCharm for a class used within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275168/typing-hints-pycharm-for-a-class-used-within-itself). Although this question asks about Pycharm, it is not really Pycharm specific and solves your problem. TL;DR: change to: `List['PlayersOnline_Result']`

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel

Comment: In particular, use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768146/5014455

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!  Those references were just what I was looking for!